# Is there a hyphen before "hundred" when used in adjective form?

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

For example:

> He had two-hundred dollars.
>
> He lived for one-hundred years.

I have never put a hyphen before hundred in situations like those, but according to [this](https://www.ncsu.edu/ncsu/grammar/Hyphen3.html) (unsure of its reliability, however), it says:

> . . . *one-hundred dollars* is hyphenated because *one-hundred* is a compound adjective standing before *dollars* . . .

From the example since "xxx-hundred" is modifying something (dollars/years), making it an adjective, should I therefore put a hyphen in between?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an adjective in those expressions, and is not normally hyphenated. Your source is wrong in describing it as an adjective.

It is a quantifier, which is grammatically quite different from an adjective.

On the other hand, suppose a casino has chips of different denominations, one of which is 100. Then one might speak about "a one-hundred chip": in this phrase, it would be adjectival, and so hyphenated. This is quite different from "one hundred chips".

Answer (score 2):

Well, all the compound numbers between 21 and 99 are hyphenated. There are [some rules to write numbers with hyphens.](http://www.grammarbook.com/numbers/numbers.asp)

Said that...

> Thirty two - *incorrect* 
>  Thirty-two - *correct*.

The rule also applies if a number between 21 and 99 is being used as an adjective *(Grammarly Handbook)*. So, in your case, it would be...

> *...two hundred dollars* 
>  *....one hundred years*

But...

> *Twenty-five hundred dollars.*

Also, note this -

> *Six thousand and seventy-two*

Further reading [here](http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000125.htm) and [here](http://www.grammarly.com/handbook/punctuation/hyphen/11/hyphen-in-compound-numbers/).